# Not able to update multiple data using eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel to build an application. Also, I am using Eloquent ORM.

There are two tables:

```
meetings - id(PK), name, meeting_with, meeting_on
user_meetings - id, meeting_id (FK -meetings (id) ), user_id
```

```
    {
      "data" : {
        "meeting_details" : {
          "id" : 8,
          "name" : "Client",
          "meeting_with" : "CEO",
          "meeting_on" : 1431588871

        },
        "user_details" : {
                "2" : "Second User",
                "1" : "First User"
          }
      }
    }
```

This is the JSON post that I am getting. I need to update in two tables - meetings and user_meetings

I am able to update the meetings table, but not able to update user_meetings table.

```
foreach($meetings_data['data']['user_details'] as $user_id => $user_name) {
            $update_array_set['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $user_meeting_result = UserMeetingDetails::where('meeting_id', '=', $meeting_id)->update($update_array_set);
}
```

I get the user_id from `user_details`.

So, if there are two users corresponding to one `meeting_id`, and if I try to update it to only one, it updates that, but also keeps the second entry. And, if the JSON has only one object under user_details, there needs to be only one object in database corresponding to a `meeting_id`

Answer (score 0):

Read this section of the documentation again:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete

If you set up the relationships correctly in your model, you can simply use $model->push() and it will update all the relations as well.

Comment: Yes, I did. But not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For many to many relationship, I figured that updating won't be the correct thing to do.

So, instead, I delete all the entries corresponding to a id and then insert the new entries.